# Insert data from text file into a table SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-io

I have a large text file, i.e. Samples.txt file, every 8 line is a one row to be inserted into a table in sql server and the data is in the following format in the mentioned text file,

> Company Name:Xpress Care
>
> Sector:Transportation and storage
>
> Operation Type:Logistic Services
>
> License Number:D-39277
>
> Expiry Date:2012-07-18
>
> Contact Numbers:0771709155 / 0789444211
>
> Email:naikmalemail@hotmail.com
>
> Address:House 119, Street 4, Taemany, District 4

So far I wrote the following code in an attempt to bring it into a format so that I can insert into the table like the following.

```
insert into table(company, sector, operation, license, expiry, contact, email, address) Values ('Xpress Care','Transportation and storage','Logistic Services','D-39277','2012-07-18', '0771709155 / 0789444211','naikmalemail@hotmail.com','House 119, Street 4, Taemany, District 4');
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int linecounter = 1;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\sample.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            // splite with the : delimeter
            string[] values = line.Split(':');
            //Console.WriteLine("column name:- {0} value:- {1}",values[0],values[1]);

            //hashtable to store the key value pairs from the text file
            Hashtable myHT = new Hashtable();
                          
            // I AM STUCK here!!! I want to add to and keep the values for 8 lines 
            myHT.Add(values[0], values[1]);
                       
//if linecounter is 8 then I have the values for one new row to be inserted  in the table
            if (linecounter == 8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\r code to insert the  values in the query example below from the hashtable\n\r");
              
// insert into table(company, sector, operation, license, expiry, contact, email, address) Values ('Xpress Care','Transportation and storage','Logistic Services','D-39277','2012-07-18', '0771709155 / 0789444211','naikmalemail@hotmail.com','House 119, Street 4, Taemany, District 4');


                 // reset the linecounter and empty the hashtable here for the next row to insert
                linecounter = 0;
            }

            linecounter++;
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

What I am trying to do with the code is that I want to add and keep the key value pairs into a `HashTable` for 8 lines, so that I can use the 8 values to insert into the 8 columns in the table in the `if(linenumber==8)` condition part but now it only keeps the value from the last line only.

I will really appreciate your kind help and ideas. If you have trouble understanding the problem, please let me i will explain with more details or if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to move the declaration and initialization of your HashTable outside the loop and clear it when you have done the eight line block read

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int linecounter = 1;
    string line;

    //hashtable to store the key value pairs from the text file
    Hashtable myHT = new Hashtable();

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\sample.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    { 
        ....

        // Continue to add values to the hashtable until you reach the 8 row boundary
        myHT.Add(values[0], values[1]);

        if (linecounter == 8)
        {
            ..... insert ...

             // reset the linecounter and empty the hashtable here for the next row to insert
            linecounter = 0;
            myHT.Clear();
        }

        linecounter++;
        counter++;
    }
```

A part from this. I suggest to use a different class for your work. In your situation I would use a [`Dictionary<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have a strong typed approach to the problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to  created the table with all the destination fields first.then

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '../sample.txt' INTO TABLE PerformanceReport;
```

By default LOAD DATA INFILE uses tab delimited, one row per line, so should take it in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if the format in the TXT file is always the same why not use this..

` while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            // splite with the : delimeter
            string[] values = line.Split(':');
            if (values[0]== "Company Name") company= value[1];

```
        if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        string[] values = line.Split(':');
        if (values[0]== "Sector") Sector= value[1];
          ...
          ...
        insert into table(company, sector, operation, license, expiry, contact, email, address)
        (@company, @sector,.....
        ///please insure injection protection 
      }`
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a big file you can store your data in a DataTable (System.Data.DataTable) and then write it quickly using SqlBulkCopy (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy). The code would look something like this:

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\sample.txt");
        string line = null;
        int linecounter = 0;

        //structure to hold data to be written to the database
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("company");
        table.Columns.Add("sector");
        table.Columns.Add("operation");
        table.Columns.Add("license");
        table.Columns.Add("expiry");
        table.Columns.Add("contact");
        table.Columns.Add("email");
        table.Columns.Add("address");


        System.Data.DataRow row = null;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //create a new table row if the line is {0,8,16,...}
            if (linecounter % 8 == 0)
                row = table.NewRow();

            string[] values = line.Split(':');

            //put the data in the appropriate column based on "linecounter % 8"
            row[linecounter % 8] = values[1];

            //add the row to the table if its been fully populated
            if (linecounter % 8 == 7)
                table.Rows.Add(row);

            linecounter++;
        }

        file.Close();

        string connectionString = "<CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE>";
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy copy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
        {
            copy.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";
            copy.WriteToServer(table);
        }
```

You can get help creating your connection string at : [Connection strings Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

NOTE: This method assumes that you've already created a table called "MyTable" in SQL Server, and that it has the 8 varchar columns specified in the DataTable.